# Spring tool suite maven project localhost is not working

Tags: java, maven, spring-tool-suite

I am a beginner in Spring Tool Suite. I installed it on my mac machine and imported the project (It is for working an API for angular project). After that, I went to "**Right click project -> run as -> maven build..**"

On that window I gave the command "clean install" and checked the `skip tests` check box. Then when I click on run, it is showing the message like below:

> ---
>
> BUILD SUCCESS
>
> ---
>
> Total time:  10.938 s
>
> Finished at: 2019-10-10T12:38:55+05:30
>
> ---

But when I try the url on angular, it is showing the below error

> OPTIONS http://localhost:8082/home/language/?timestamp=1570691353510 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I have doubt about the port and not sure how to check that in `Spring tool suite`.

Any idea on how can I fox this? Any help could be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: run as maven will only build the project, you need to run you application as well

Comment: @Shailesh Thank you :).Can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: depends on your application type if it is plan java application or Spring boot application or something else

Answer (score 0):

Running Maven's `clean install` does not run your app. It only assembles it in a distributable package and places it in your Maven repository.

You should probably execute [`spring-boot:run`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html) to run your Spring Boot app, or a custom task (may be just `run` or `tomcat:run`) if it is an old-fashioned Spring MVC app.